# Two finite groups $G,H$ are isomophic iff $\text{rank}(G)= \text{rank}(H)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

$\newcommand{\rank}{\operatorname{rank}}$
Can you please check if the following proof is correct?

Let $\phi: G \mapsto H$ be an isomorphism. If $\{g_i\}$ is a generating set of $G$ then $\{\phi(g_i)\}$ is a generating set of $H$. Therefore $\rank(G) = \rank(H)$. Conversely if $\rank(G) = \rank(H)$, then the map $\psi: G\mapsto H$ defined between the respective generators by $\psi(g_i) = h_i$ is an isomorphism.

This proof seems incorrect. Forgive me I'm just a beginner.

Comment: Why is $\psi$ a homomorphism?

Comment: Thank you! So the statement should just be if two group are isomorphic then rank(G)=rank(H), correct?!

Comment: But the rank of these are not the same anyway right, what do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just because two groups have the same rank, that doesn't mean that the corresponding generators have the same order. Specifically, any cyclic group has rank $1$, but they aren't all isomorphic.

Note that this isn't the only thing that can go wrong either. You can have $|G| = |H|$ and $\operatorname{rank}(G) = \operatorname{rank}(H) = n$ with $G = \langle g_1, g_2, \ldots, g_n\rangle$ and $H = \langle h_1, h_2, \ldots, h_n\rangle$ with the order of $g_i$ equal to the order of $h_i$ for all $i$, and *still* have $G$ and $H$ non-isomorphic. For instance, take the two groups
$$
\Bbb Z_4\times \Bbb Z_2 \text{ versus } D_4
$$
(where $D_4$ is the dihedral group acting on $4$ elements; the symmetry group of a square). They both have $8$ elements, they both have rank $2$, and they both have a generating set with one order-$4$ element and one order-$2$ element. Yet one is abelian and the other isn't, so they aren't isomorphic.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just realised $\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2$ and $S_3$ is another example. Therefore the correct statement would be $G\cong H \implies rank(G) = rank(H)$! :)

Comment: @JohnJacob That works too. It is not quite as spectacular as the orders of the group's themselves are different, but it works. To round this off, know that it is unknown whether we can ever make a (useful) list of group properties (like abelianness, rank, order of the group, order of the elements, etc.) which are enough to decide whether two finite groups are isomorphic.